# NameNode and secondary Namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, namenode

What is the role of a Secondary namenode, if at all Namenode fails ?

Answer (score 1):

Before going into this, i will explain about roles of NN and SNN.

**NameNode:** It contains metadata of datanodes, directory tree structure, `fsimage` and edit logs related to your entire cluster

**SecondaryNameNode:** It periodically collect `fsimage` and edit logs from NN and then merge those into new `fsimage` file, again it will push back into NN to decrease the size of NN metadata

So if NN fails

1. SNN won't receive any updates from NN
2. Your entire cluster go down
3. With the help of SNN you can start another node as NN but SNN won't do NN works. It is just to collect fsimage and editlogs from NameNode

Answer (score 0):

Its role will be accelerate the startup progress. It is a helper node for NameNode and It is not the replacement or backup for the Namenode.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer by @mobin-ranjbar

Also, this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEqQMLSXQlY) will help you understand "For what purpose the Secondary Namenode is NOT meant?" ;)